# How to change AVD battery state (not battery level)

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I wish to run several testcases where in I want to test the charging state of the device. Since, AVD is always in running state, in order to fulfil the test cases, I need to programmatically toggle them from charging to discharging and vice-versa.

How do I set the device state from charging to discharging and vice-versa on AVD, where I will be running test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect to your AVD via `telnet` and call:

```
power status discharging
```

or

```
power status charging
```

From the Docs: [Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#power)

> The power command controls the power state reported by the emulator to
>   applications. The syntax for this command is as follows:
>
> power display|ac|status|present|health|capacity

Possible parameters for status:

> status unknown|charging|discharging|not-charging|full

Comment: The code you have shared works on locally where I have telnet access. I need to replicate the scenario for test case purpose, where testcases would be deployed on external environment.

Comment: @onkar hm if you can't connect to the AVD I don't think there is a way you can solve your problem

Comment: is there any provision where we can access/fire telnet commands via code ?

Comment: @onkar sry to say that but I have never heard of a way of doing that. But if you find a way it would be nice if you can post it as asnwer

Comment: sure, I will share the solution if I come across.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `adb` command to set the emulator to `unplugged` state,which is similar to `discharging`.

`adb shell dumpsys battery unplug`

Also, if you want to set the emulator to normal mode, use the following command:

`adb shell dumpsys battery reset`

You can refer to my blog post here https://sulav-timsina.blogspot.com/2021/07/adb-cheat-sheet.html
It may have some more useful adb commands.